# Using C# Timer to stop executing a Program

Tags: c#, timer

I want a program to stop executing for a certain amount of time. And i want this to happen in regular intervals. For example, i want a program to run for 5 minutes and then it should stop for 2 mintues and continue running for another 5 minutes after that. Is this possible with the C# Timer class?

Comment: What do you mean "stop running"?

Comment: Doesn't this kind of defeat the purpose of event-driven programming?

Comment: assuming you have windows forms app you can "freeze" the UI for certain interval. Not a good idea though. Loop through the controls and enabled=false and finally this.enabled=false (for the main form); Use Control.Invoke() to call a method that does disabling the UI controls from timer elapsed event. msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/… Not a great idea... but just a thought...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `Thread.Sleep()` passing in the number of milliseconds to pause execution for.

Comment: However I wouldn't recommend calling `Thread.Sleep()` for a 2-minute duration.  Windows will think the program has crashed, and will display "Not responding" in the title bar.  There's no way he can want  this behaviour.

Comment: Very good point.  As long as it's not being called on the main/UI thread it will not cause that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is desirable behaviour, so if you update your question you might get a better answer than this.

You can use a timer that does little more than toggle a variable (e.g. bool).  If that bool is used by the application, then you can use it to control whether the application is "running".

I'm suggesting this instead of `Thread.Sleep()` because at least your application is still responsive.  If you want to pause a non-UI thread, then `Thread.Sleep()` will suffice, but **don't** call `Thread.Sleep()` on the UI thread, even with very short durations.

Answer (score 0):

As previous answer say: what is 'stop'? The user can't use the program for 2 minutes? If so you could pop a modal dialog (with text) and the user can't close it.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Windows Forms application, you might want to consider moving this into a threaded execution model. You can do this using either the `BackgroundWorker` control, thread pooling with the `ThreadPool` class, asynchronous methods *Begin* and *End* (such as `Stream.BeginWrite`), or by manually handling the thread yourself (bit more complex).

A `BackgroundWorker` will provide the easiest form of development by allowing you to handle events for the asynchronous code, and update a progress bar or label to show the current state of the execution. This will allow you to use `Thread.Sleep` without the system warning the user that the application has hung.

Basically, in Windows Forms development you should be using some form of threading to handle long executions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Window.Forms.Timer to register a callback each 1000ms

```
        private int counter;
        void StartTimer()
        {
            counter = 0;
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 1000;
            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        }
```

In the event function simply increment a global counter variable that executes when
a condition fulfills

```
        private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            counter++;
        }
```